# How do I do VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH for more than one range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have been trying to figure out a way to fill up the ratings column (image below) without getting into lengthy formula. I have tried `VLOOKUP` and 'INDEX`/`MATCH` but have gotten to a dead end.

In a normal `VLOOKUP` there is only max of 2 columns for table_array, i.e. G2:J3 based on my example. But I wanted to select the table_array based on year (G3:G5), is there a way to do so?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: I don't see an easy solution - I'm not even sure a complex array formula could accomplish this. One problems is that that data points you have on the left are year and rating but on your axes on the table on the right are year and a quality assessment (with rating being in the data portion of the table). Even so, I am not sure off hand that would matter if changed. If the table on the right were changed to such that it resembled {2004,Good,1.9; 2004,Average,1.2; 2004,1.1; 2005,Good,1.6;2005,Average,1.3;...} where there were 3 columns and new rows started where you see a semi-colon (cont)

Comment: ...I could then write an array formula that would populate the column on the left table. But with the current layout you would probably need to write a VBA script to automate the process.

Comment: It isn't clear what your rating cutoffs mean (minimum, maximum, or mixed).  They aren't consistent, and don't handle the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(OR(D3>VLOOKUP(B3,G:J,2,FALSE),D3=VLOOKUP(B3,G:J,2,FALSE)),$H$2,IF(AND(D3<VLOOKUP(B3,G:J,2,FALSE),OR(D3>VLOOKUP(B3,G:J,3,FALSE),D3=VLOOKUP(B3,G:J,3,FALSE))),$I$2,$J$2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions may not be well thought out.  You have ranges that appear to be minimum cutoffs (the score must be >= to qualify for that rating).  However, there are scores below "Bad" with no Rating name.  If the cutoffs are a maximum for each Rating, there is no rating better than the Good cutoff.  If the cutoffs are a mix (high for Bad, low for Good), that would define the Average, so how do you use the Average cutoff?

Here's an approach to a solution that you can modify if you redefine the ranges.  It's based on the cutoffs being minimums for each rating.  This requires the Ratings table to be in ascending order.  It is scalable in that you only need to adjust the range of the lookup table; it doesn't require a separate lookup formula for each year:

[image]

Values that are not defined by your rating cutoffs return an error; it wasn't clear how you would want to remedy it.  The formula in E3:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$J$2,,MATCH(D3,INDIRECT("$H$"&MATCH(B3,$G$1:$G$5,0)&":$J$"&MATCH(B3,$G$1:$G$5,0))))
```

INDEX returns the Rating name based on the MATCH result.  MATCH compares the Score to the Rating cutoffs.

It determines which row of the lookup table to use by matching the Year.  INDIRECT creates the correct lookup range from that result.